# Scroll text like Yahoo Finance widget on iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I would like to build a a UI control just like the Yahoo Finance widget we see on the pull-down menu on iOS5. It seems to be a scrollview which scrolls subviews horizontally continuously. But when you touch it, the scrolling stops. Now, if you drag your finger you can scroll manually. But as soon as you release it it restarts scrolling in a very smooth way. How should I build a control like that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read up on Core Animation and also handling touch events (or use gesture recognizers).

UIScrollView probably isn't the right tool for this job since it expects its content to be finite. The zipper-type view that you seem to describe might not have an end -- it'll work more like a continuous loop, and it may not even repeat itself. Using Core Animation, you can animate your view(s) sliding horizontally at whatever rate you like. Stop the animation when you get a touch or gesture and use a different animation to have the view track the touch.